# Registering beforeunload event in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive which I use to warn the user if they attempt to close the window or navigate away without saving their changes:

```
app.directive('dirtyTracking', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            function isDirty() {
                var formObj = getProperty($scope, $element.attr('name'));
                return formObj && formObj.$pristine === false;
            }
            //So we can read string keys such as foo.bar and correctly
            //traverse the javascript object
            function getProperty(obj, prop) {
                var parts = prop.split('.'),
                    last = parts.pop(),
                    l = parts.length,
                    i = 1,
                    current = parts[0];

                while ((obj = obj[current]) && i < l) {
                    current = parts[i];
                    i++;
                }

                if (obj) {
                    return obj[last];
                }
            }

            function areYouSurePrompt() {
                if (isDirty()) {
                    return 'You have unsaved changes.';
                }
            }

            window.onbeforeunload = areYouSurePrompt;
            //window.addEventListener('beforeunload', areYouSurePrompt);

            $element.bind("$destroy", function () {
                window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', areYouSurePrompt);
            });

            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
                var prompt = areYouSurePrompt();
                if (!event.defaultPrevented && prompt && !confirm(prompt)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

As it currently stands, **this works**, but as you can see, I have to explictly set the `window.onbeforeunload` property. The problem with this approach is that if I have other directives that want to do things on the save event, they will clobber each other.

When I attempted to use `window.addEventListener` or `$window.addEventListener` the event does not seem to work as expected.

Stepping through the debugger, the code **does** enter the `areYouSurePrompt` function and **does** return the string, however I am not prompted with a confirm dialog before the window closes.

I am aware I can use the approach where I save the current value of `window.onbeforeunload` but I'd rather figure out why using the `addEventListner` isn't working as expected.

Comment: The event onbeforeunload will be fired outside angular. Please add $scope.$apply();  at the end of the callback